# How to test for WebApp features that require secure contexts?

Tags: browser, configuration, webcrypto-api

I have a few applications relying on hash functions, which were developed a while ago before browsers changed their policy to restrict `Crypto.subtle` to HTTPS connections.

Deploying the webapps on secure connection isn't a problem for me, but testing them locally is.

How can I test for SubtleCrypto, and other features that require secure contexts to work? Is there an option in `about:config` that I can tweak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers now treat `localhost` and loopback IP addresses (`127.0.0.0/8` and `::1/128`) as secure, which is a big favor done to developers. See [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/secure-contexts/).

Answer (score 4):

Probably too late to help you, but there's a config flag available on Chrome that allows you to specify insecure contexts that should be considered secure.

On Chrome, open [chrome://flags](http://chrome://flags) and search for the flag "Insecure origins treated as secure". Add the insecure context domains you want to test on and relaunch the browser. Works for me.

I couldn't find a similar flag on Firefox.

Comment: It's never too late. If it's late for me, it might still be just in time for others. Anyway, using Chrome has added advantage of being able to test USB and Bluetooth functionalities.